# Cannot add a column named 'Text': a nested table with the same name already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am getting the following Error while loading the XML in Dataset in C#.

ERROR : Cannot add a column named 'Text': a nested table with the same name already belongs to this DataTable.

I know that error is caused by the  tag present in the XML but how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Check Relations on `DataSet`. At least one of them (with child table Text) have `Nested=true`. Changing Nested to `false` will resolve the issue.